# Prove that $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx \geq af(a/2)$ if $f''(x) > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm trying to solve the problem below, but I'm running into some problems. I hope you can help me.

[image]

**Solution** Using the Integral Mean Value Theorem, we get:

$\exists \xi \in (0,a) : \int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx=f(\xi)a$

Using the fact that the function is convex, since $f''(x) > 0$, we get the following inequality:

$f(\frac{a}{2})\leq \frac{f(a)+f(0)}{2}$

How can I continue from here? I don't really know how to get rid of the 0, as I don't know whether the function maps to every set of real numbers.

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f''(x) > 0$ means that the function is (strictly) *convex,* so that its graph lies above the tangent at the point $x=a/2$:
$$
 f(x) \ge f\left( \frac a2 \right) + f'\left( \frac a2 \right)\left(x-\frac a2 \right) \, .
$$
(You can also prove this with Taylor's theorem, if needed.)

Integrating this inequality over $[0, a]$ gives the wanted result
$$
 \int_0^a f(x) \, dx \ge a f\left( \frac a2 \right)
$$
since the integral over the second term is zero.